# Commandline.todirectory? System.Diagnostics.Commandline Object to string? variable?

Tags: powershell, command-line, tostring, system.diagnostics

*After **Get-Proccess**, I am unsure how I may extrapolate a part of the data and use that data in a command.*

```
(Get-Process magic)[0].CommandLine
```

*Returns*

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\System32> "\\NAS\NAS_Software\Program\Magic.exe" "\\NAS\NAS_Database\TestSubject\"
```

*I would like to utilize the given (test subject) directory in the results as the path in the Copy-Item.*

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\XXXXXXXXX\" -Include *0.dcm -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination C:\Subjects\New
```

As I am not a programmer, I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction before I go down the wrong rabbit hole of objects, strings, etc...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code snippet (I use *hardcoded* `$x`):

```
$x   = '"\\NAS\NAS_Software\Program\Magic.exe" "\\NAS\NAS_Database\TestSubject\"'
# $x = (Get-Process magic)[0].CommandLine
$arg = ($x | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ' ' -Header prog, arg).arg
$arg                                        ### \\NAS\NAS_Database\TestSubject\
Get-ChildItem -Path "$arg" -Include *0.dcm -Recurse | Copy-Item -Destination C:\Subjects\New
```

In the described particular case (no spaces in paths), the following would work as well:

```
$arg = $x.split(' ',[StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)[1].Trim('"')
```

However, I'd prefer the [`ConvertFrom-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertFrom-Csv?view=powershell-7) cmdlet to correctly handle possible space(s) in any part of `$x`.

Answer (score 0):

The commandline property is already a string (only powershell 7 has this).  This is really a question about how to get part of a string.  I would do this.  `-split` into the first word, then use `Split-Path` to get the directory, and `-replace` the double-quote with nothing.

```
$commandline = '"\\NAS\NAS_Software\Program\Magic.exe" "\\NAS\NAS_Database\TestSubject\"'

(split-path (-split $commandline)[0] ) -replace '"'

\\NAS\NAS_Software\Program
```